# Show that $\omega'(x_k)\neq 0$

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots

For $x_0, \ldots , x_n\in \mathbb{R}, \ x_j\neq x_k$, we define the polynomial $$\omega (x)=(x-x_0)\cdots (x-x_n)\in \Pi_{n+1}$$ Show that $\omega'(x_k)\neq 0$ and that the polynomials $$\ell_j(x)=\frac{\omega(x)}{(x-x_j)\omega'(x_j)}, \ j=0, \ldots , n$$ have the property $\ell_j(x_k)=\delta_{jk}, \ j,k=0, \ldots , n$.

We have that $$\omega'(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^n(x-x_j)$$ right? Each $x_i$ makes one term of the product to zero, but not the whole expression, right?

Can we just say that to prove that $\omega'(x_k)\neq 0$ or is there an other way to prove that formally?

Comment: Correct. That seems formal enough for me. Just a typo, $i,j$ go from $0.$

Comment: Ah yes! So we cannot show the proposition "Each $x_i$ makes one term of the product to zero, but not the whole expression" using formulas to make it more formal, can we? @Phicar

Comment: Well, you can but I do not see the point. You can do something of the form. Suppose $\omega '(x_k)=0$ then every summand is zero, meaning that for every $i,$ $\prod _{j\neq i}(x_k-x_j)=0,$ implying that for $i=k$ you have $\prod _{j\neq k}(x_k-x_j)=0,$ which implies that $x_k=x_j$ for $j\neq k.$ Contradiction.

Comment: Ah ok! Does every summand have to be zero because the product cannot be negative? @Phicar

Comment: Well is because all but one summands are already $0$ because $k$ is in the product. So, for it to be $0$ you need all summands to be $0.$

Comment: Ahh yes! I see!! As for the second part.... Do we have that $$\ell_j(x)=\frac{\omega(x)}{(x-x_j)\omega'(x_j)}=\frac{(x-x_0)\cdots (x-x_n)}{(x-x_j)\prod_{i\neq j}(x-x_i)}=\frac{(x-x_0)\cdots (x-x_n)}{\prod_{i}(x-x_i)}=1$$ or am I missing something where we should ise $x_k$ ? @Phicar

Comment: not that fast, that is if $x=x_j.$ but if not, then what happens?

Comment: I got stuck right now. At whch point do we use the fact if $x=x_j$ or if $x\neq x_j$ ? @Phicar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $j\leq n,$ then
$$\ell_j(x)=\frac{\omega(x)}{(x-x_j)\omega'(x_j)}=\frac{\prod _{i=0}^n(x-x_i)}{(x-x_j)\omega'(x_j)}=\frac{\prod _{i\neq j}(x-x_i)}{\prod _{i\neq j}(x_j-x_i)},$$
so if $x=x_k$ there are two options i.e., either $k=j$ and everything cancels out or $k\neq j$ and the numerator vanishes.

Comment: I got it!! Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: @MaryStar You are welcome. Well done!